# Sums of squares in global fields (Reference Request)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, global-fields

There is a result due to Siegel that, for a number field $K$, any totally positive element of $K$ is the sum of four squares of $K$. This is discussed in another question ([sum of squares in ring of integers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14456/sum-of-squares-in-ring-of-integers)).

Is the result true in the more general setting of global fields? That is, for an algebraic function field $F$ is a totally positive element the sum of four squares?

Of course, in the number field terminology *totally positive* requires embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}$, which we do not have in the function field setting. So (I believe) we say an element $f \in F$ is *totally positive* if $f$ is a square in $F_{\infty}$, the completion of $F$ at the nonarchimedian infinite place $\infty$.

Comment: Usually a global (function) field is the field of rational functions of an algebraic curve over a finite field. Is that what you have in mind? Then could you explain what is the "nonarchimedian infinite place $\infty$"?

Comment: @abx Yes, an algebraic field extension of $\mathbb{F}_q (t)$ where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$ and $q = p^n$ elements, and $t$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the $F$ I have in mind. In which case the prime at infinity is the ideal of $F$ generated by $\frac{1}{t}$ with corresponding valuation equivalence class denoted by $\infty$. This place $\infty$ is nonarchimedian and infinite. It takes value $v_{\infty}(f) = -\deg(f)$ for $f \in F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corollary 1.5 on page 379 of Lam's *Introduction to quadratic forms over fields* (in the Sums of Squares section) states that if $F$ is any nonreal global field then every element of $F$ is a sum of four squares. Since you say you are interested in finite extensions of $\mathbb F_q(t)$, and all fields of characteristic other than $0$ are necessarily nonreal, it follows that the answer to your question "yes".