# Lagrange's four squares theorem in other fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

Is something known about analogues of Lagrange's four squares theorem in number fields other than $\mathbb{Q}$?

I'm more interested in the case of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

For example, is it true that any positive number in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ can be represented as sum of several squares from the same field?

Comment: Do you think that $-1$ can be represented as a sum of squares in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Well yeah, surely i need to add word "positive".

Comment: Sums of squares are *totally positive* (i.e., positive under all embeddings of the field in $\mathbb R$). Conversely, any totally positive element in any number field can be written as a sum of four squares, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/14473 .

Comment: So, for example, $a+b\sqrt3$ is a sum of four squares in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$ if and only if both $a+b\sqrt3$ and its conjugate $a-b\sqrt3$ are positive, i.e., $a\ge|b|\sqrt3$.